# creating triggers and functions in postgresql

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

how can i create a `trigger function` before `adding/updating`,the `function` should check records that have the same `id` (i.e comparison by `id` with existing `objects` that have the same property as the `temporary_object`)If a record with the id is found, then that entry is set to the `time_dead`, and then it adds an entry containing the corresponding values ​​of the attributes found in that record (except those that are set for a new record), when `time_dead` is empty then `time_create` of a new time is equal to that time at the current moment . Thus,a new record `time_create` is like the `time_dead's` ancestor.
If a record with that id is found then it is added to the database with the establishment as the `time_create` of the current time.

for example here is a simple explanation(just for explanation purposes)

```
id time_create   time-dead  student  amount

 1  06.12           07.12    henry   500

 1  07.12                    henry   1000
```

so if a student called henry with id 1 entered a room at 06.12  and left at 07.12 the next time he enters another room again time_dead will be equal to time_create(so time_dead of old entry and time_create of new entry - will be equal)
these are my tables below in sql format

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_object
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  time_create timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  time_dead timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT temporary_object_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, time_create)
)

CREATE TABLE persons
(
  fname text,
  fsurname text,
)
INHERITS (temporary_object)


CREATE TABLE rooms
(
  roomnum integer,
  course integer,
  passport text,
  students_number text
)
INHERITS (temporary_object)
```

this is what i am trying to do but im afraid i do not know how to finish it but im 100% not right  may some help out

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON persons
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE func1();
```

and this is the function

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $persons$
 DECLARE
        time_create          integer;
        time_dead     timestamp;
        id       timestamp;
    BEGIN

 IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

            time_create=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't tell you what I'm missing from your question, but I try to answer what I think I understood.

Row level triggers can access the version of the row affected with the `NEW` and `OLD` variables (depending on `TG_OP`).  In this case, you can use `NEW`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$persons$
DECLARE
    i integer;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
    THEN
        UPDATE persons 
        SET time_dead = NEW.time_create
        WHERE 
            id = NEW.id -- we are looking for the same ID
            AND time_dead IS NULL
        ;
    ELSE -- UPDATE
        -- do here something
    END IF;
END;
$persons$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is only a starter, modify it to your needs.